# Как задать высоту div в зависимости от ширины?

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, css3

Допустим есть блок div со стилями:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 30%;
    height: ???;
    margin-left: 35%
```

Как сделать, чтобы высота составляла, к примеру: 200% ширины или 50% ширины?

Comment: Если речь о ширине экрана - vw https://habrahabr.ru/post/126863/

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что значит *"200% ширины или 50% ширины"*? Проценты относительно чего?

Answer (score 1):

Если под словом "ширины" вы имеет ввиду ширину экрана, то нужно использовать единицу измерения `vw`. К примеру, `100vw` равно ширине окна браузера.

```
div {
    height: 200vw;
}
```